# Get Cookies from a Driver and use them to Login in another Driver

Tags: c#, selenium

So I want to get cookies from my first selenium Chrome Driver and use it to login to another driver. Could you help me ?

Comment: what exactly is yourproblem? What did you try? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow - we're here to help with coding problems but we're not a coding service. Can you please have a go at solving your question then add a specific problem if you need further assistance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [the code in the selenium docs](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/support_packages/working_with_cookies/)?

Get all cookies

```
var cookies = driver.manage().getCookies();
```

Adding cookies:

```
Otherdriver.Manage().Cookies.AddCookie(new Cookie("key", "value"));
```

Have a go at building a loop around one to add to the other an feel free to post some code if you get stuck